# Use Entity Framework 6 to Create a NUMBER column in Oracle db 19 without precision and scale

Tags: c#, database, oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using EntityFramework 6.4.4 code first to create a database. My database server is Oracle 19C. One of the fields in my database is a currency field (decimal) and this field, let's call it Price, will be multiplied by big decimal values most of the time, but also sometimes with small values, so I need the percision and scale to be flexible to accomodate all value sizes.

In the old system, the field had the Datatype `NUMBER`, but that was set up directly with PLSQL, now no matter what I try using EF6 (C#), I keep getting `Number(18,2)`.

I looked online and found [from this article](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/datatypemapping.html) that this is C#'s decimal conventions, and that I [may disable it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.conventions.decimalpropertyconvention?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=entity-framework-6.2.0).

So in my code, I disabled it in the `AppDbContext` like this:

```
using TestDB.Model;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;

namespace TestDB
{
    public class MyDbModel : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<DecimalPropertyConvention>();
            .
            .
        }
```

But the result that I get is now `NUMBER(38,0)` which is the Oracle default.

What do I have to do to set a field's data type as `NUMBER` without percision and scale?
Or is that not supported by EF6?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of disabling conventions, override them with explicit column [configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/types-and-properties).  eg

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Property(x => x.Price).HasColumnType("NUMBER");
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have already tried it. If `DecimalPropertyConvention` is not disabled it will come up with the convention default `Number(18,2)` otherwise with `Number(38,0)`. Since I work with the EF6 and not with EF Core, I have already tried `.HasPrecision`. But here you always have to include the presicion and scale.